# What if I offer bounty but got no answers per week

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I want to ask, what happens with reputation in case if someone offers some reputation as a bounty for a question, but during bounty time there is zero answers (or given answers are deleted by moderators because they are useless).

Does reputation goes back to person who offered the bounty or it just vanishes?

Comment: You don't get your rep back. You pay for the extra attention, not for guaranteed answers.